# Android Studio - Seleccionar archivo PDF en Android 12

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Requiero de poder seleccionar un archivo para poder enviarlo por Retrofit. Pero después de seleccionar el archivo y de poder obtener su información, obtengo el siguiente error al enviarlo con Retrofit:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/319db0ac0c280ff1cc37aa201a121809.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Lo extraño es que este código funciona para android 9, 10 y 11, pero falla en el emulador en android 11, 12 y en un dispositivo físico con android 12.

Mi proyecto tiene como objetivo la API 31.

En el manifiesto tengo agregado `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`.

Para abrir la UI del sistema y seleccionar el PDF tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void doBrowseFile() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download");
        Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        chooseFileIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        chooseFileIntent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri);
        chooseFileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        chooseFileIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        chooseFileIntent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFileIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.selec_file));
        activityResultPickFile.launch(chooseFileIntent);
    }
```

En attachedFile es donde asigno la referencia del archivo, que posteriormente envío por Retrofit.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultPickFile
            = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                        String filePath = null;
                        try {
                            FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils(this.getContext());
                            filePath = fileUtils.getPath(fileUri);
                            attachedFile = new File(filePath);

                            ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

En ese punto, no consigo problema alguno. Puedo obtener nombre del archivo, tamaño del PDF, y todo funciona bien. Pero al enviarlo por Retrofit, es donde sucede el problema.

```
val attachFileRequest: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "file",
                        attachFile.name,
                        RequestBody.create(
                                mimeFile.toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                                attachFile
                        )
                )
                apiService.sendFile(
                        attachFileRequest
                ).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseAPI?> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseAPI?>, response: Response<ResponseAPI?>) {
                        ...
}

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseAPI?>, t: Throwable) {
                        t.printStackTrace()
                        
                    }
                })
```

Finalmente el error que arroja es el siguiente:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/319db0ac0c280ff1cc37aa201a121809.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
W/System.err:     at okio.Okio__JvmOkioKt.source(JvmOkio.kt:182)
W/System.err:     at okio.Okio.source(Unknown Source:1)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$asRequestBody$1.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:176)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.kt:157)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.kt:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:203)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:533)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
W/System.err:   ... 13 more
```

Les agradecería cualquier ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de actualizar tu aplicación para apuntar a Android 11 (nivel de API 30), el sistema ignorara el atributo `requestLegacyExternalStorage` cuando tu aplicación se ejecuta en dispositivos con Android 11 o posterior.

El uso de `requestLegacyExternalStorage` para futuras versiones del sistema operativo esto definitivamente se restringirá, por lo que te recomiendo usar ahora `getExternalFilesDir()` para este propósito, revisa los ejemplos:.

Crear directorio usando **getExternalFilesDir()**

```
   File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/nombrecarpeta/");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
```

Esto creará el directorio y la estructura:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/nombrecarpeta/
```

Crear archivo usando **getExternalFilesDir()**

```
  try {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Fernandosfile.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Esto creará el archivo "gerardfile.txt" dentro de la estructura:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/Fernandosfile.txt
```

Comment: No pretendo crear una copia del archivo en el directorio. Aunque puede ser una solución interesante para otros problemas.

Comment: No puedes escribrir fuera de /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/ , actualmente esta serìa la ùnica ubicaciòn de tu archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar mi error.

Lo primero es guardar en una variable InputStream el contenido del archivo seleccionado en cuanto obtenga la Uri en el onActivityResult:

```
InputStream myInputStream= getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
```

Y en el momento de enviar el archivo en Retrofit, en lugar de enviar un objeto File, envío myInputStream:

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
    "file",
    attachFile.fileName,
    RequestBody.create(
        mimeFile.toMediaTypeOrNull(),
        myInputStream.readBytes()
    )
)
```

Ante la necesidad de una respuesta, [en esta otra publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534853/android-studio-pick-pdf-file-and-upload-with-retrofit-open-failed-eacces-pe) encontré la solución.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.